# Show that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{(1-u^4)^{1/4}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function

Show that $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{du}{(1-u^4)^{1/4}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$.

Not sure if it is helpful to anyone but 
$\int \frac{du}{(1-u^4)^{1/4}} = f^{-1}(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $f(x)^4 + f ' (x)^4 = 1$.

Also $f(x)$ can be expressed as a hypergeometric function.

Comment: I think you mean $\text{d}u$?

Comment: Thanks +1 I did not notice myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as
\begin{align*}
2\int_0^1\frac{du}{\sqrt[4]{1-u^4}}&=\frac12\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-\frac14}t^{-\frac34}dt=\frac12B\left(\frac34,\frac14\right)=\\&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2\Gamma(1)}=\frac{\pi}{2\sin\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, the beta function. Indeed 

Comment: But how did you simplify those gamma expressions ? I gave +1 but feel that is a bit missing.

Comment: @mick [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula): $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)= \frac{\pi}{ \sin\pi z} $.

Comment: Right. I think the answer is complete now. Although the connection between gamma and beta is not explained , this is a classic and easy too find - I think. +1.